# Unable to refer javascript array from another javascript file

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I am trying to create a chart using highcharts in which i am not able to fetch data which i store in another js file.

My main.js file has all the code for creating chart. It has the section of series.

```
series: [{
            name: 'Desktops',
            data: '/data/desktop.js',
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
```

Here i want to refer data from another js file. The name of file is desktop.js and it has just the below array

```
var desktopData = [[1475272800000, 117759], [1475359200000, 106147], [1475445600000, 147747], [1475532000000, 302031], [1475618400000, 520539], [1475704800000, 245353], [1475791200000, 180376], [1475877600000, 78819], [1475964000000, 90466], [1476050400000, 257822], [1476136800000, 284465], [1476223200000, 242898], [1476309600000, 297186], [1476396000000, 268069], [1476482400000, 183149], [1476568800000, 410442], [1476655200000, 1117798], [1476741600000, 1274668], [1476828000000, 1331799], [1476914400000, 1230213], [1477000800000, 888251], [1477087200000, 572050], [1477173600000, 931144], [1477260000000, 1556641], [1477346400000, 1526736], [1477432800000, 1310133], [1477519200000, 1207422], [1477605600000, 785556], [1477692000000, 487264], [1477778400000, 787714], [1477868400000, 942663]];
```

How can i refer array defined in another file?

Comment: remove `var desktopData = ` and the trailing `;` to deliver JSON instead of a javascript variable: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing#3

Comment: Plus, make sure that your file with data is loaded document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //do work
});

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use any type of the framework? To load JS file in another file, you need to require it somehow, either by using AMD, ES imports or any other way (be it synchronous or asynchronous).

If you are just adding the files to the HTML (using script tags), then the only thing you have to do is to make sure that the files are loaded (`DOMContentLoaded` event) and then, you have to attach the data to a global scope.

Global scope in the browsers is called a `window` and every time when you use variable that was not declared in your scope by `var` it means that the JS is searching for it in the global scope. In order to assign something to a global scope you can just omit `var` or explicitely assign it like this:

```
window.desktopData = [];

// And then in another file, assuming that the data is ready

var myData = window.desktopData
```

Please also remember that including files in `<script>` tags usually means that they will block your browser and the order of the files matters (at least when you want to rely on the fact of one file already loaded before another file). I'd suggest using some kind of import system then:

http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html